# Extract string + numbers from a field in PostgreSQL

Tags: regex, postgresql

So far what I know about PostgreSQL pattern matching:

1. extract first continuous part of digits.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('X2Y1234445Z2', '([0-9]+)');
```

2. Check if string contains substring pattern: `cuid:` .

```
select ' cuid: 7812789sioeudkl290380 cuid: 1812789' ilike '%cuid: %';
```

3. But following return false.

select ' cuid: 7812789sioeudkl290380 cuid: 1812789' ilike '%cuid: [0-9]+%';

So for the String: ' *cuid: 7812789sioeudkl290380 cuid: 1812789*', **expect** extract *cuid: 7812789* **and** *cuid: 1812789*. Let's assume, before  and after ***cuid:*** have arbitrary number of white spaces.

Edit:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(' cuid: 7812789sioeudkl290380 cuid: 1812789', '\s*cuid\s*[0-9]+');
```

But this way returns nothing.

Comment: It returns nothing because you have a `:` after `cuid`, and in your regular expression (`'\s*cuid\s*[0-9]+'`) you do not have a `:` .

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT regexp_matches(' cuid: 7812789sioeudkl290380 cuid: 1812789', '\s+cuid:\s+[0-9]+','g');
```

> g flag which commands it to return all matches, not just the first
> one.